# CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour) returns the wrong angle

Tags: c#, emgucv, contour, angle

I have a contour of a number plate and I want to check if it's tilted or not. I used `CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour)` but it always returns the `angle == -90` even when the plate is obviously tilted, you can see the contour I draw in the picture below.

[image: return values]

[image: contour draw]

[image: original image]

Does anyone know what happened and solution for my problem?

Here is the code:

```
Image<Gray, byte> gray = new Image<Gray, byte>("2.PNG");
Image<Gray, byte> adaptive_threshold_img = gray.ThresholdAdaptive(new Gray(255), AdaptiveThresholdType.GaussianC, ThresholdType.BinaryInv, 11, new Gray(2));

VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
Mat hier = new Mat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(adaptive_threshold_img, contours, hier, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

double max_area = 0;
VectorOfPoint max_contour = new VectorOfPoint();

for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
{
    double temp = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]);
    if (temp > max_area)
    {
        max_area = temp;
        max_contour = contours[i];
    }
}

VectorOfVectorOfPoint contour_to_draw = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint(max_contour);
CvInvoke.DrawContours(gray, contour_to_draw, 0, new MCvScalar(255), 2);

CvInvoke.Imshow("plate", gray);

RotatedRect plate_feature = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(max_contour);

CvInvoke.WaitKey();
CvInvoke.DestroyAllWindows();
```

Comment: Please provide us with an [mcve] of your code. It's impossible to say whether there's a problem in EmguCV (less likely) or your code (more likely).

Comment: I've just updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CvInvoke.threshold()` instead of `gray.ThresholdAdaptive()`. Set proper threshold and you'll get better contour than before.